# SAS determine first and last non-missing ID / date by class for each variable

Tags: sql, sas, proc, summary

I want a report of all the variables in my longitudinal/panel data set by city.  `PROC MEANS` has been great for this, but this cannot handle the inclusion of columns stating the first and last date for which the variable in question is nonmissing.

My data looks something like this:

```
data have;
input date $ city $ var1 var2 var3;
      datalines;
2006Q1  NYC   .  0.1   4
2006Q2  NYC   .  0.48  6
2006Q3  NYC   .  0.55  7
2006Q4  NYC   5  0.33  2
2007Q1  NYC   8    .  10
2007Q3  NYC  12    .   15
2006Q1  BOS  11  0.6   .
2006Q2  BOS   6  0.81  .
2006Q3  BOS   1  0.66  9
2006Q4  BOS   2  0.5   1
2007Q1  BOS   4  0.61  8
2007Q3  BOS  19  0.4   1
;
run;
```

My desired output is a table that looks something like this:

```
City Variable  First Nonmiss  Last Nonmiss
 BOS    var1   2006Q1         2007Q3 
 BOS    var2   2006Q1         2007Q3 
 BOS    var3   2006Q3         2007Q3 
 NYC    var1   2006Q4         2007Q3 
 NYC    var2   2006Q1         2006Q4
 NYC    var3   2006Q1         2007Q3
```

Perhaps a `PROC TRANSPOSE` with a `create table` in `PROC SQL` is the best way to do this, but I'm open to suggestions -- and I'm not really certain where to start.

Thanks!

Comment: This is definitely impossible in `PROC MEANS` (it's not one of the statistics `PROC MEANS` offers).  You should either restructure this question to ask how to calculate this generally (quite possible) or, given this is calculated, how to report this in a way that is similar to `PROC MEANS` output (also quite possible).  The two things are sufficiently different, though, I don't see them as one question.

Comment: Darn.  Thanks for confirming that @Joe.  I've reframed the questions accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely do a `proc transpose` approach here; it's very straightforward.  This takes advantage of the fact that `first.` and `last.` are defined *after* the `where` clause is implemented.

```
proc sort data=have;
  by city date;
run;

proc transpose data=have out=have_t;
  by city date;
  var var1-var3;
run;

proc sort data=have_t;
  by city _name_ date;
run;

data want;
  set have_t;
  by city _name_ date;
  retain first_nonmiss;
  where not missing(col1);
  if first._name_ then do;
    first_nonmiss = date;
  end;
  if last._name_ then do;
    last_nonmiss = date;
    output;
    call missing(of first_nonmiss);  *I like to do this for safety even though it is irrelevant here - later code might make it relevant;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: This is fantastic. Thank you!  I just want to make sure I understand what's going on in that last `data` step. So, the `where not missing(col1)` subsets the data by `col1` and the `if first.` and `if last.` simply returns the respective rows this is true for each group(?).  And, the `by city _name_ date` command creates these city/_name_ groups automatically?  Also, why is the `retain first_nonmissing` there but not for `last_nonmiss`. (The `call missing()` is still beyond my comprehension, but always happy to learn best practices!)

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to get this output with PROC MEANS/SUMMARY but you need to transpose the data so that may disqualify my answer.

```
data have;
input date $ city $ var1 var2 var3;
      datalines;
2006Q1  NYC   .  0.1   4
2006Q2  NYC   .  0.48  6
2006Q3  NYC   .  0.55  7
2006Q4  NYC   5  0.33  2
2007Q1  NYC   8    .  10
2007Q3  NYC  12    .   15
2006Q1  BOS  11  0.6   .
2006Q2  BOS   6  0.81  .
2006Q3  BOS   1  0.66  9
2006Q4  BOS   2  0.5   1
2007Q1  BOS   4  0.61  8
2007Q3  BOS  19  0.4   1
;
run;
proc print;
   run;
data want;
   input City $ Variable $  First_Nonmiss $ Last_Nonmiss $;
   cards;
 BOS    var1   2006Q1         2007Q3 
 BOS    var2   2006Q1         2007Q3 
 BOS    var3   2006Q3         2007Q3 
 NYC    var1   2006Q4         2007Q3 
 NYC    var2   2006Q1         2006Q4
 NYC    var3   2006Q1         2007Q3
;;;;
proc print;
   run;
proc transpose data=have out=havet name=variable;
   by city date notsorted;
   var var:;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
proc summary data=havet nway missing;
   class city variable;
   where not missing(col1);
   output out=want2(drop=_:)
      idgroup(out(date)=first_nonmiss)
      idgroup(last out(date)=last_nonmiss)
      ;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
proc compare base=want compare=want2 listequalvars;
   run;
```